# React-admin dataProvider does not trigger AUTH_ERROR of authProvider

Tags: react-admin

Good afternoon, all react-admin users. I am using this awesome open-source project and I have been struggling for hours.

As stated in the documentation, if any API calls return any error, the authProvider will catch it with type AUTH_ERROR. However, in my case, authProvider is not triggered. Thank you for reading this. Any help would be much appreciated.

AuthProvider:

```
export default async(type, params) => {
  if (type === AUTH_ERROR) console.log('testing')
}
```

dataProvider:

```
class dataProviderHttpError extends Error {
  constructor(status, message) {
    super(message)
    this.status = status
  }
}

export default (type, resource, params) => {
  return Promise.reject(new dataProviderHttpError(401, 'testing'))
}
```

Admin

```
import dataProvider from './dataProvider'

<Admin
  dataProvider={dataProvider}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

authProvider will catch any authentication error you make it listen for and return a `Promise.reject()`
On your example you just tell your authProvider to show something on your console and then on your dataProvider you try to return a `Promice.reject()`.
This is a task for your authProvider, not your dataProvider.
You can check again the part of the documentation that explains how to handle AUTH_ERRORS on the authProvider [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md#catching-authentication-errors-on-the-api).